# inequality problem in Spivak Calculus

Tags: inequality

Can somebody please explain why it immediately follows that for $$ (x-1)^2+1>0 $$ all x are admissible? 
(This problems is found in Spivak's Calculus, 3rd edition, Chapter 4, problem (v) )

Comment: Because the square is always positive. $x=1$ ??? then $=$. So $\ge$ in general.

Comment: thank you, it is obvious now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $(x-1)^2\geq 0$ for every $x\in \Bbb R$ and so $(x-1)^2+1\geq 1>0$ for every $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: thank you, it is obvious now

Comment: @Eugene you're welcome :).